# Set value and select radio button in Jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons with values CARD1 and CARD2 respectively and both the radio button name is Field_22 (Group).

I want to set the value or select the radio button CARD1 or CARD2 based on a value that is in another variable - TotalOrderCost in document load.

I am using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    if(TotalOrderCost ==0)
    $('input[name=FIELD_22]').val(['CARD1']);
    else
    $('input[name=FIELD_22]').val(['CARD2']);

});
```

Just wanted to know if the above code will set the value of FIELD_22 and as well as select the appropriate checkbox?

Help!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
if(TotalOrderCost ==0)
$('input[name="FIELD_22"][value="CARD1"]').attr('checked','checked')
else
$('input[name="FIELD_22"][value="CARD2"]').attr('checked','checked')
```